# What will happen if a MOSFET switch circuit is run without the source?

Tags: mosfet, powermosfet

I have a situation where I have to supply the power to the MOSFET gate drive circuit permanently even when the main switch for source battery is turned off. It is because of the fact that the drive circuit is connected to the alarm unit and therefore, requires to be ON indefinitely. However, since battery has master switch, which can be turned off thus resulting in a circuit break for the MOSFET switch. So, I wonder if MOSFET would be fine hanging without the source present while Vgs being provided constantly?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVTL4T.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Show your circuit please.

Comment: there isn't a circuit yet. I want to know the possibility of building such a circuit.

Comment: So you want us to guess the exact circuit you're thinking of building?

Comment: added the schematics of what I mean.

Comment: You can still power your driver circuit with this configuration.

Comment: Changed the position of the switch in the circuit. Will it still be OK?

Comment: There is no reference for Vin regards to the battery. What is the return path for Vin, where is it refereced to?

Comment: edited to remove the confusion now.

Comment: R3 would need to be across the switch contacts.

Comment: @Andyaka thats the whole point of the question!

Comment: OK, but what does this mean: *I wonder if MOSFET would be fine hanging without the source present*

Comment: @Andyaka when the SW1 is open, and Vgs is supplied to the gate.

Comment: What do you mean by "hanging without the source present"? I make a lot of time to answer questions and that means I try to understand them but, in your question, you need to explain what you mean more precisely.

Comment: If your current requirements are low, you may consider using a depletion mode mosfet rather than an enhancement mode mosfet. A depletion mode mosfet conducts when the \$V_{GS}\$ gate-source voltage is 0, and stops conducting when the gate-source voltage is high.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Current requirement is high. Would it solve if SW2 is used instead of SW1?